# How to display console.log output from JavaScript to HMTL5 page

Tags: javascript, html

The goal is run the game.html, so that it will call the JavaScript and run rockpapergame.js.  Using the Chrome Browser, then Inspect, at Sources, I can look at the debugger and step over the function for the referenced js at script src="rockpapergame.js", and step through the rockpapergame.js.  However, I get only the prompt for: userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?").

How do I return the console.log output to the HTML5 page?

```js
// Rock, Paper, Scissors Game //
// rockpapergame.js          //

var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      return "The result is a tie!";
    }else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
          return "rock wins";
        }else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
              return "paper wins";
            }else {
              return "scissors wins";
            }
        }else {
          return "paper wins";
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
// end of rockpapergame.js//
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Little Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div></div>
    <p><b>About this Game</b></p>
    <script src="rockpapergame.js"></script>
    <p>This is a cool game</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - `console.log` logs the values in the browser's console, usually used for debugging purposes. If you want to show the result of your game on page, create a named container, and set it's html - for example by creating DOM element `<div id='content'></div>` and using `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = computerChoice`

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: The short story is, I need to write an application in XML using js to parse data and return the output to the application using XML.  I'm able to parse the data and present using Python 2.7, but need to use XML as presentation method and will use js to parse.  I'm learning js and haven't gotten to Data Structures and Objects for JavaScript yet, will hit these in the next two days!  As I'm beginning with the basics I wanted to know what the syntax is move data from JavaScript to HTML5. (the back story has much more detail).  Sorry to kill this thread with blah, blah blah!

Answer (score 5):

Following two possible solutions.

01)
As others have pointed out in comments, `console.log()` print always a result in browser console and not in the HTML of your page but you can change its behavior  monkey patching (overwriting) the default `console.log` function provided by the browser, a really simple version could be:

```js
console.log = function(message) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
};
console.log('your result');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

PS: I personally I would not suggest you to override `console.log` default behavior.

02)
You could add a div container of your result in your HTML page, and use that DIV to show the result for your game.

Modified version from your question:

```js
// Rock, Paper, Scissors Game //
// rockpapergame.js          //

var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Computer: " + computerChoice;
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      return "The result is a tie!";
    }else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
          return "rock wins";
        }else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
              return "paper wins";
            }else {
              return "scissors wins";
            }
        }else {
          return "paper wins";
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
// end of rockpapergame.js//
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Little Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div></div>
    <p><b>About this Game</b></p>
    <script src="rockpapergame.js"></script>
    <p>This is a cool game</p>
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```